# Telling AngularJS to update the selected option of a select

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angularjs

Recently I've been working on a web app, and I need one `<select>` element for each day of the year.

So I did something like this, where `daysOfYear` is an array of all the days of a year, and `availableValues` is an array of all the possible values.

```
<div ng-repeat="day in daysOfYear">
  <select ng-model="day.value" ng-options="value for value in availableValues"></select>
</div>
```

The problem is that it is **very very slow**, something like **5 additional seconds to load** in Firefox, during which the browser is completely frozen. Note that there is already a 2-seconds freeze when calculating `daysOfYear`. Without the selects I have a 2 seconds freeze, with the selects I have a 7 seconds freeze, so **I'm sure that is it caused by the selects**. Also there is an additional small freeze whenever I change the value of one of the selects.

So I decided to follow an advice that I read on a newsgroup and write my own module that will fill the `<select>`.
My modules (see the code below) adds any `<select>` with a `app-typeslist` directive to an array. Then the list of `options` is loaded from the server, and all the elements in the list are filled with the given options.

The problem is that AngularJS doesn't detect this modification in the options list. The `<select>` has no `value` attribute, and contains an additional `<option>` element which represents the "invalid value" state.
**Is there a way to tell AngularJS that I want it to update this select?**

Thanks.

---

*Here is the source code for the module. I don't think it is necessary at all to answer the question, but I guess that you will ask for it anyway:*

```
(function() {
    var elementsList = $();
    var html = null;
    angular
        .module('elementsTypes', [])
        .config(function($compileProvider) {
            $compileProvider.directive('appTypeslist', function() {
                var directiveDefinitionObject = {
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        elementsList.push($(element));
                        if (html)
                            $(html).each(function() { $(this).clone().appendTo(element); });
                    }
                };
                return directiveDefinitionObject;
            });
        })
        .run(function($http, $rootScope) {
            $http.get(url of the types).success(function(data) {
                html = $();
                angular.forEach(data, function(category) {
                    var gr = $('<optgroup/>').attr('label', category.description);
                    angular.forEach(category.elements, function(elem) {
                        $('<option/>').attr('value', elem.name).text(elem.description).appendTo(gr);
                    });
                    html.push(gr);
                });
                elementsList.each(function() {
                    var e = this;
                    $(html).each(function() { $(this).clone().appendTo(e); });
                });
            });
        });
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I completely removed `ng-model` from the `<select>`, and extended my module to include the binding.

```
(function() {
    var elementsList = $();
    var html = null;

    var refreshElement = function(node) {
        var newVal = $(node).data('appTypeslist');
        $(node).val(newVal);
    };

    angular
        .module('elementsTypes', [])
        .config(function($compileProvider) {
            $compileProvider.directive('appTypeslist', function() {
                var directiveDefinitionObject = {
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        elementsList.push(element);
                        if (html)
                            $(html).each(function() { $(this).clone().appendTo(element); });
                        scope.$watch(attrs.appTypeslist, function(newVal) {
                            $(element).data('appTypeslist', newVal);
                            refreshElement(element);
                        });
                        $(element).change(function() {
                            $(element).data('appTypeslist', $(this).val());
                            scope.$apply(attrs.appTypeslist + ' = "' + $(this).val().replace(/([\\"'])/g, "\\$1").replace(/\0/g, "\\0") + '"');
                            refreshElement(element);
                        });
                    }
                };
                return directiveDefinitionObject;
            });
        })
        .run(function($http, $rootScope) {
            $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
                html = $();
                angular.forEach(data, function(category) {
                    var gr = $('<optgroup/>').attr('label', category.description);
                    angular.forEach(category.elements, function(elem) {
                        $('<option/>').attr('value', elem.name).text(elem.description).appendTo(gr);
                    });
                    html.push(gr);
                });
                elementsList.each(function() {
                    var e = this;
                    $(html).each(function() { $(this).clone().appendTo(e); });
                    refreshElement(e);
                });
            });
        });
})();
```